# One Hot Encoding with multiple tags in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, one-hot-encoding

I have a simple dataset.

```
id,question,category,tags,day,quarter,group_id

1,What is your name,Introduction,Introduction,1,3,0

2,What is your name,Introduction,"Introduction, work",1,3,1
```

Now if you see, in the `tags` column there are multiple inputs seperated by commas. If I try to one-hot-encode using *pandas* `get_dummies` function I will get that as a single column. But I wanted to create columns for each tags. How can I do that possibly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe need [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = df['tags'].str.get_dummies(', ')
print (df1)

   Introduction  work
0             1     0
1             1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `pivottable` of panda's dataframe method. 
the following code might be useful

```
pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['id','question','category','day','quarter','group_id'],columns=['tags'])
```